# A number with digits $2$ and $5$ is divisible by $2^{2005}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I found an old problem on a website but no answer is given. Here is the problem :

Prove that there is a unique positive integer consisting entirely of digits $2$ and $5$, having exactly $2005$ digits and divisible by $2^{2005}$.

Here is where i am : it must finish with a $2$, but i have absolutely no other clue.

Comment: Can you see why it must end with 52 in the next step instead of 22?

Comment: Is it because the number must be divisible by $2^2=4$ and $52$ is divisible by $4$ but not $22$ ?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.

Comment: Also its must end with $552$ because it must be divisible by $8$

Comment: I continued like this and found it must end with $255552$ because we can divide it by $64$

Comment: The pattern continues at each step. Given the last $n$ digits, if they form a number divisible by $2^{n+1}$ (rather than just $2^n$), then insert a $2$ at the beginning. Otherwise, insert a $5$ at the beginning. Keep going until you have $2005$ digits.

Comment: The simple inductive proof is given in the 2nd bullet in the answer in the linked dupe.